# "Unless" at the end of the sentence

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, unless

I was just wondering what does it mean when people use of the word "unless" at the end of the sentence. As far as I know, I only hear people say something like "Unless you work hard, you will fail." They usually use the word "unless" at the beginning of the sentence, or otherwise, use it as a conjunction, but never seen it at the end of the sentence before. (I'm not a native speaker.)

I found this in the TED talk. Could you please explain me what does it mean?
(Here is the link : https://www.ted.com/talks/larry_smith_why_you_will_fail_to_have_a_great_career?language=en)

The transcript:

> **And that's why you're not going to have a great career. Unless.**
>   "Unless." That most evocative of all English words—"unless." But the
>   "unless" word is also attached to that other, most terrifying phrase,
>   "If only I had ..." "If only I had ..." If you ever have that thought
>   ricocheting in your brain, it will hurt a lot. **So, those are the many
>   reasons why you are going to fail to have a great career.
>   Unless—Unless.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the *unless* in quotation marks, the word never appears at the end of a sentence in your example...

But it could!

In the paragraph you quote, the part that normally would follow *unless* has been left out. It's left to the reader's (listener's) imagination to fill it in.

This is used quite a lot:

> Unless you study very hard, you will not succeed this year.

is equivalent to:

> You will not succeed this year unless you study very hard.

Now look at this:

> You will not succeed this year. Unless...

This leaves it to the student to decide what needs to be done in order to succeed. Studying very hard, a miracle happening, or maybe something else.

The effect is similar to the use of *or else*:

> You'd better do as I tell you, or else...

What happens if I don't listen is not said, but I am left to imagine what the speaker might do (to me) if I don't comply!